# Wordpress XMLRPC

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc

Is there a way for me to post as a "contributor" using XMLPRC?  Even if it just shows up in the Draft's section to be approved by someone of a higher level?

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually...

Assuming you're using the metaWeblog API, you can call: metaWeblog.newPost(blogid, username, password, struct, publish)

Where the publish parameter should be 'draft' or 'publish'.

Much better than hacking xmlrpc.php!

Comment: So using metaWeblog.newPost() would circumvent Wordpress Security and allow a Contributor to post Directly?  IF so let me know, I did already hack XMLRPC but would rather not go that route if I can do it without altering actual code.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with whether or not you can restrict a user to only posting drafts via XMLRPC.  But hacking xmlrpc.php to make all posts drafts would do the trick and it worked for me.